# can QGIS show current Location or not

Tags: google-maps, location, interactive, qgis

guys can QGIS display the current location like google maps or it does not support the interactive map features

i was trying to find a way to display the current location but i cant find the solution anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not directly possible to receive the current device location in QGIS. You could add a gps to your pc and use the *[GPS Information Panel](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html)*. Getting the location, based on the internet connection, is (afaik) not possible and would be very inaccurate. If you want to use a mobile client: Check out *[QField](https://qfield.org)*.